# Intellij not showing coverage

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, intellisense, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I wrote one test case for the controller. Inside that controller, calling one service class method.
When I Selected RunAsCoverage in the IntelliJ test case got passed. But it shows test coverage only for the controller class. For the service class, it's showing 0 percent.

When I run test coverage with the Jacoco plugin it's showing for both controller and service class

Please help with this. Thankyou